# Spring MVC 4.0 - RequestMapping without value, fallback on methodname

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, java-ee-6

So I have this controller class, and would like to use the method name as the requestmapping value. I believe this used to work.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="start/*")
public class StartController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String home() {
        return "{}";
    }

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String test2() {
        return "{}aaaaa" ;
    }
}
```

But now I get this error:

```
There is already 'startController' bean method
    public java.lang.String mypackage.App.controllers.StartController.home() mapped.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'startController' bean method
public java.lang.String mypackage.App.controllers.StartController.test2()
        to {[/start],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'startController' bean method
public java.lang.String mypackage.App.controllers.StartController.home() mapped.
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It seems as I can only have one default requestmapping for the index.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Spring documentation this was no longer possible since Spring 3.1:

There are also several things no longer possible:

> Rely on method names as a fall-back mechanism to disambiguate between
>   two @RequestMapping methods that don't have an explicit path mapping
>   URL path but otherwise match equally, e.g. by HTTP method. In the new
>   support classes @RequestMapping methods have to be mapped uniquely.

[See Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-31-vs-30)